# Set UIButton instance highlighted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have lots and lots of UIButtons, kept in a UIScrollView, all of which are dynamically tagged.

I can retrieve the button's properties, such as its tag, outside of its creation method by creating a reference to it. However, I am unable to set properties on the button, i.e. more specifically, I can't seem to setHighlighted.

Here is an example:

```
//UIButton is created elsewhere, i.e. UIButton *createdButton... createdButton.tag = 101
//Trigger method with createdButton as SENDER

- (void)highlightButton:(id)sender {

UIButton *buttonInstance = (UIButton *)sender;
int tag = buttonInstance.tag //use this to perform button-specific code

[buttonInstance setHighlighted:YES]; // <-- Not setting

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the `button` in `[button setHighlighted:YES];` come from? Did you mean `buttonInstance`?

Comment: where you use buttonInstance ?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Just updated the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlighted` is typically a transient state, used to indicate that the user is touching the button. As such, it will often be re-set to `NO` by UIKit in the normal course of touch handling events. This seems particularly likely in your case since the method is called by an action on the button itself.

If you want to persistently change the appearance of a button, you should set `selected` rather than `highlighted`. You can set titles, images etc. for this control state (`UIControlStateSelected`) in the same way as you are setting them for `UIControlStateHighlighted`.